# How to override a DependencyProperty windows 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I am extending the functionality of a TextBox. How can I to override the Text DependencyProperty?

I would need to add some code in the `set` method and I cannot use the TextChanged event because I need to execute the code before the assignment.